# How to use case with in operator

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Have query like :

```
declare @case int =  1

SELECT a.column1,b.column2
FROM tbl1 a
INNER JOIN tbl2 b on a.id = b.id and a.category in(1,2,3,4,5)
```

Need when `@case =  1` category must be in (1,2,3,4,5), when `@case =  2` it must be (1,2,4,5).
Something like this :

```
 SELECT a.column1,b.column2
 FROM tbl1 a
 INNER JOIN tbl2 b on a.id = b.id and (CASE WHEN @case = 1 THEN a.category in(1,2,3,4,5) WHEN @case = 2 THEN (1,2,4,5) ELSE '')
```

How to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a.column1,b.column2
FROM tbl1 a
INNER JOIN tbl2 b on a.id = b.id 
                 and 
                 (
                     (@case = 1 and a.category in (1,2,3,4,5)) OR
                     (@case = 2 and a.category in (1,2,4,5))
                 )
```

<sub>I added parentheses for readability. Not all of them are necessary.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is better but if you did happen to want to do it with case you could do it like

```
SELECT a.column1,b.column2
FROM tbl1 a
INNER JOIN tbl2 b on a.id = b.id and 
    (    CASE WHEN @case = 1 and a.category in(1,2,3,4,5) THEN 1
              WHEN @case = 2 and a.category in(1,2,3,4) THEN 1 
              ELSE 0
         END
    ) = 1
```